# jQxgrid override focus when dynamically setting page size and page size options

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqxgrid

```
var sUSR_DisplRows = 'number that comes from DB';
var iNum = parseInt(sUSR_DisplRows);
var count = 0; //because each grid will trigger the event
    jQ("#onegrid, #twogrid, #threegrid").on("bindingcomplete", function (event) {
       if(count == 2){
           CustomScript.reshape(sUSR_DisplRows, iNum);
       }
       count ++;
    });
}

function reshape(sUSR_DisplRows, iNum){
    //here I set the page size base on the user saved number
    jQ('#onegrid').jqxGrid({ pagesize: iNum});
    jQ('#twogrid').jqxGrid({ pagesize: iNum});
    jQ('#threegrid').jqxGrid({ pagesize: iNum});
    if(sUSR_DisplRows < 10){
        jQ('#onegrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: [sUSR_DisplRows, '10', '20']});
        jQ('#twogrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: [sUSR_DisplRows, '10', '20']});
        jQ('#threegrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: [sUSR_DisplRows, '10', '20']});
    }else if(sUSR_DisplRows >= 10 & sUSR_DisplRows < 20){
        jQ('#onegrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: ['5', sUSR_DisplRows, '20']});
        jQ('#twogrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: ['5', sUSR_DisplRows, '20']});
        jQ('#threegrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: ['5', sUSR_DisplRows, '20']});
    }else{
        jQ('#onegrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: ['5', '10', sUSR_DisplRows]});
        jQ('#twogrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: ['5', '10', sUSR_DisplRows]});
        jQ('#threegrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: ['5', '10', sUSR_DisplRows]});
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I set the page options the page will focus on the grid division. 
I need to override or eliminate this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried after setting the pagesizeoptions or pagesize to call the Grid's focus method to focus it or use $("#myJQ").focus() syntax?

Comment: Scripto, the problem is that when I run the code it scrolls down to the grids and back up because I use scroll(0, 0); or any other known way to set the focus. However, it makes the page jumps and I am trying to avoid that from happening.

Comment: Apparently jQ('#onegrid').jqxGrid({ pagesizeoptions: ['5', '10', sUSR_DisplRows]}); has a default behavior to focus and I need to override it